# How to convert decimal to hexadecimal using brain?

Tags: math, hex, decimal

Since I knew how to manually convert hexadecimal to decimal using this method.
Read from right to left, the last digit multiplied by the constant value 16 and plus the first digit.

```
For example:
12h = 2 + (1 * 16) = 18
99h = 9 + (9 * 16) = 153
```

How do I convert back into hex from decimal?

Comment: Who's brain are you talking about ??

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, the goal of StackOverflow is to be the definitive reference for all programming questions. Just because an answer exists somewhere else does not mean it isn't welcome here.

Comment: @MarkRansom ... unless that "somewhere else" happens to be the official documentation, I assume?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

As you can see in the picture above. You need to draw a  table in your *brain*

Lets take 456 as example.

If we **divide 456 by 16** . **Remainder = 8 & Quotient = 28**

We further **divide 28 by 16** and get **remainder = 12 & quotient = 1**

Now further **dividing 1 by 16** results in **remainder = 1 and quotient = 0**

So we stop.

Now we take the remainders, bottom up.

**1 , 12 , 8**

Converting 12 in hex notation gives **C**.

So the answer is **1C8**

Comment: So we basically Math.floor() the quotient?

Answer (score 4):

To convert from decimal to hex you must know the powers of 16. 16^1 is obviously 16; 16^2 is 256; 16^3 is 4096; 16^4 is 65536; etc.

For each power of 16, divide the number by that power to get one hex digit. Then take the remainder and divide by the next lower power of 16.

This is enough of a hassle that it's easiest to let a calculator do it, or use a scripting language such as Python.

Comment: learning the multiples of 16 by heart to quickly convert bytes between hex <=> decimal doesn't seem much of a hassle to me. It does kinda add up after 10 bits, though.